# Close/Destroy JIRA connection JAVA

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm a beginner in Java coding.
Below is the code

```
public class AddJIRATicketWatcherCommandHandler {

private final JiraFactory jiraFactory;

public void handle(String jiraIssueKey, String watcher) {
    
        log.debug("Adding {} watcher to JIRA issue: {}", watcher, jiraIssueKey);

        final Issue issue = jiraFactory.createClient().getIssueClient().getIssue(jiraIssueKey).claim();
        log.debug("Found JIRA issue: {}", issue.getKey());

        Promise<Void> addWatcherPromise = jiraFactory.createClient().getIssueClient().addWatcher(issue.getWatchers().getSelf() , watcher);
        addWatcherPromise.claim();
 }}




public JiraRestClient createClient() {
    log.debug("Creating JIRA rest client for remote environment");

    URI jiraServerUri = URI.create("");

    jiraServerUri = new URI(StringUtils.removeEnd(jiraConfig.getJiraURI(), "/rest"));

    JiraRestClient restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,
            jiraConfig.getJiraUsername(),
            jiraConfig.getJiraPassword());

    JIRA_LOGGER.info("url=[{}], username=[{}], password=[{}]", jiraServerUri.toString(), jiraConfig.getJiraUsername(), jiraConfig.getJiraPassword());
    log.debug("JIRA rest client created successfully for remote environment");
    return restClient;
}
```

However, when I ran the sonarqube. I received this error.

Use try-with-resources or close this "JiraRestClient" in a "finally" clause.

[image]

My understanding is to close the connection once done. But, I'm unsure on how to do that.

I tried to implement finally with close(). But the results is still showing the same error.

[image]

Comment: put the JiraRestClient in a variable and call the `close()` method on it in a finally block. Or use  try-with-resources

Comment: I tried, try{



} finally {

restClient.close();

} , but it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with resources:

```
    public void handle(String jiraIssueKey, String watcher) {
    try (JiraRestClient restClient = jiraFactory.createClient()) {
        log.debug("Adding {} watcher to JIRA issue: {}", watcher, jiraIssueKey);

        final Issue issue = restClient.getIssue(jiraIssueKey).claim();
        log.debug("Found JIRA issue: {}", issue.getKey());

        Promise<Void> addWatcherPromise = restClient.getIssueClient().addWatcher(issue.getWatchers().getSelf() , watcher);
        addWatcherPromise.claim();

    }
}
```

try finally:

```
public void handle(String jiraIssueKey, String watcher) {
    JiraRestClient restClient = jiraFactory.createClient();
    try {
        log.debug("Adding {} watcher to JIRA issue: {}", watcher, jiraIssueKey);

        final Issue issue = restClient.getIssue(jiraIssueKey).claim();
        log.debug("Found JIRA issue: {}", issue.getKey());

        Promise<Void> addWatcherPromise = restClient.getIssueClient().addWatcher(issue.getWatchers().getSelf() , watcher);
        addWatcherPromise.claim();

    } finally {
        restClient.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to use that code and run in sonarqube. However, the error result is still the same

Comment: Hmm, you should replace your other calls to `jiraFactory.createClient()` with the restClient variable. So that you will only once create the connection and close that one. 
But then it still looks like sonar is complaining about the `restClient` you added and closed... Im not sure whats wrong with that, maybe it will disappear if you change the other calls to  `jiraFactory.createClient()`? Or does sonar tell something usefull when you press 'why is this an issue'

Comment: Hi Willem, after that I tried the first approach (try with resources) and apparently it's working perfectly well. Thanks!